# How to bypass a country blocked web page on Xidel?

Tags: xidel

say I run this on terminal:

```
xidel -se '//span[@id="last_last"]' 'https://www.investing.com/currencies/xau-usd'
```

but what happened after is this:

`Error:
Internet Error: -4 
when talking to: https://www.investing.com/currencies/xau-usd`

how to bypass that website and got the result what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write code to bypass it if it is country blocked. To bypass such a security you need your IP to match the prefix that a certain country is using which is usually done through VPN.

Comment: how about the `--proxy` option, i'm not familiar with proxy, so I couldn't use it.

Comment: If you would have proxies available then sure you could use it but some websites also have proxy protection.

Comment: There's also VPN detection, test https://ipinfo.io/

Comment: You might want to use residential proxies to bypass detection. However, some IP geolocation provider like IP2Proxy has capabilities to detect residential proxies as well. But you can always test it.